# Camera suddenly sees much less than usual

Tags: canon, dslr, sensor, light-meter, sensitivity

I've been out taking pictures all day without any real problems. After getting home I wanted to take one last quick shot, in that moment I realized my camera was struggling to turn on, after a while it did, but everything looked darker, like suddenly it was less sensitive to light (Taking a picture in a bright room at 1/125 F3.5 and ISO100 looked painfully dark, when I know for a fact it shouldn't).

Before I turned my camera off, I had my ISO set to 6400 (was taking night-time pictures), that's the only suspicion I have regarding this. I've tried resetting the camera, reinstalling the firmware, changing lenses, cards and modes. So far I've found nothing to fix my issue.

I could really use some insight on what might be wrong with my camera and what are possible ways of fixing it. Camera model is a Canon EOS250/SL3

To provide some more information: Also tried charging the battery, still same thing. Live view and picture look dark, viewfinder looks as normal as ever. Should also mention the light-meter readings are lower than usual.

Comment: what does live view look like, if your camera supports it?

Comment: You didn't mention if you made sure the battery was charged...

Comment: Does everything appear dark when looking through the viewfinder too, or just in the photos taken?

Unless you are shooting fully manual, is the exposure compensation set to 0? If it is at e.g. -3 your images will turn out too dark.

If you take a photo with the camera in A-mode (Automatic), does it still turn out too dark?

If you set the lens to e.g f/11 and press the DOF button, does the aperture of the lens move?

Comment: Everything looks fine through the viewfinder. But the light-meter detects everything at a lower range than usual, live view and pictures look far darker. 

Camera modes don't make any difference as far as I've seen.

Regarding the DOF button, my camera doesn't have one, but from my tests on both my leses it seems the aperture still works.

Comment: if you shoot in aperture priority mode, set it to the lowest ISO and widest aperture - does the camera select an appropriate shutter speed or one that's too long?

Comment: But if you shoot in e.g. AV mode and set the Exposure Compensation needle to 0, are the photos still too dark?
https://cpn.canon-europe.com/content/education/infobank/exposure_settings/exposure_compensation.do

Comment: Shooting in AV does make it all look brighter (With Exposure Compensation set to 0), but when looking at the Shutter Speed, it is far slower than it really should. 

I'm using a single room's lighting as reference for that, I've taken pictures in there before at 1/125 no problem, but now my camera needs to reach 1/4 or so to get to the same brightness level as it used to.

Comment: well, being able to shoot at 1/125 of a second would only be a matter of bumping the ISO or opening the aperture further.
Sounds to me like you used to have ISO on Auto, but now it is set to e.g. 100. (you did mention having set the ISO to 6400 in your original post)
If you set ISO to Auto, and Exposure Compensation to 0, aren't you closer to the shutter speed you remember?

Comment: I tend to shoot on manual, so I've got a decent idea of how my parameters should be depending on the situation, and I can't recall a single occasion in which I used my ISO on auto, not to mention I checked that early on.

As an example, I've taken several pictures in my office, I the lighting stays the same as long as the blinds are closed, so I'm using it as a reference.

I've got pictures taken in that room at 1/125, F5.6 and ISO100. And they looked fine, but if I try to now, those settings are too dark. And when shooting in AV for example, it goes all the way up to 1/4 or more.

Comment: Have you changed the Metering Mode to e.g. Spot Metering then?
It is of course possible that the sensor has been damaged, but I haven't heard of it before.

Comment: I have tried that as well, unfortunately, that doesn't seem to make any substantial difference either.

My main suspicion was sensor damage too, but it doesn't make any sense, I've done nothing that could cause damage to the sensor, I mostly shoot in dark enviroments. Its almost like the camera is at an ISO below 100

Comment: Is there a neutral density filter on your lens?

Comment: Indoor office at  1/125, F5.6 and ISO100 is certainly not right..... that environment is about 7-8 ev for iso 100 that would be something more like f2.8 1/15....the only explanation is that your camera screen used to automatically compensate for severely underexposed images (with those settings you are at least 5-6 stops underexposed)

Answer (score 2):

Now your metering is **normal**.

You say you used to take good pictures in an Indoor office at 1/125, F5.6 and ISO100 that is certainly not right...
impossible in fact if your office isn’t a solarium or a special light testing lab...

that environment is about 7-8 ev for iso 100 that would be something more like f2.8 1/15

[indoors EV](https://books.google.fr/books?id=6NIDBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA17&lpg=PA17&dq=indoor%20office%20ev&source=bl&ots=bZOF2j6kAj&sig=ACfU3U0s24HZYBOmFDv8vLOIPJIcwU3XfA&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiw-MXY4KbqAhUj4YUKHeBfAJUQ6AEwCnoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=indoor%20office%20ev&f=false)

With the settings you used you were at least 5-6 stops underexposed.
For that aperture/speed the correct iso would likely be in the 6400 range

I looked at your camera extended manual
[250D manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/4/0300034864/02/EOS_250D_Advanced_User_Guide_EN.pdf)

The (wrong) setting you used to have were automatically compensated by the auto lighting optimizer

- exposure compensation
  It is the [+/-] setting at the bottom of your viewfinder. It could have been previously set at +5 resulting in severely under-exposed images, and now is reset at 0. If you want to be sure not to accidentally modify it look at page 449 of the manual for how to disable it in custom functions. Better keep it active though if you can remember to keep an eye on it and adjust it as needed.
  P 160

> If the exposure is too dark, turn the <6> dial clockwise while holding
> down the  button (for increased
> exposure).

- wrong exposure

It is very easy with manual settings to overlook that the small exposure bar is way, way on the far left (> -5) Even very experienced photographers sometimes dial up settings they want and forget to check it.

- Auto lighting optimizer

I think this is the likely culprit in your case, the manual refers to it in pages 136 & 160. It camouflaged the original underexposure issue.

> If the image comes out dark or the contrast is low, the brightness and contrast can be corrected automatically. This function is called Auto Lighting Optimizer. The default setting is [Standard]. With JPEG images, the correction is applied when the image is captured.
> In Basic Zone modes, [Standard] is set automatically

And p 160

> z If [z: Auto Lighting Optimizer] (=136) is set to any setting other than [Disable], the image may still look bright even if a decreased exposure compensation for a darker image is set

Your present “predicament” is either due to the exposure being correct now, hence not needing auto ajustements and/or you accidentally switching off that auto compensation (which is a good thing) and now you are seeing the images at their native state.

N.B. You may be tempted to reset it at the wrong values to continue taking pictures the way you were but réalise that you pay a hefty quality price for that sever under exposure. Sometimes you do it if you can’t get the picture otherwise but it is generally better to increase the iso, or do both like underexposing by 1-2 stops and increasing the iso by 3-4 stops